# 14.04 Login incorrect ('Retry' placeholder in password field)

Tags: 14.04, login

it happened to my system after hard shutdown.
Now on login screen I see placeholder 'Retry' in the password field, I can't type anything.

Login screen snapshot:

[image]

Then I decided to watch what terminal says (ctrl+alt+f1):

terminal snapshot:

[image]

Proper login doesn't work at all. Always get "login incorrect".

What is that? Some broken auth package?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a broken package, repaired it through **recovery mode -> repair broken packages.**